# OpenCV (android) convert a unknown type image to CV_8UC3

Tags: android, opencv

First, I have no idea what is the type of user input images.
But I want to convert all of them to type CV_8UC3.

I use this function :

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(img,img,CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

But it doesn't work.

And I try this :

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(img_edge,img_edge,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
```

This is from gray to RGB, but actually I have no idea what is the type of the input image, I just want to convert all of them to CV_8UC3.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to write an `if-else` clause, there are not too many cases, only 2 formats other than RGB exist, One bring Gray and the other being RGBA. So you may go like:

```
if (img.channels() == 1) {
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img_edge,img_edge,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
} else if (img.channels() == 4) {
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img_edge,img_edge,Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, images generally come in these 3 flavors only: Gray, RGB and RGBA